# How to get all processes running on each CPU core in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, process, cpu-usage, multi-core

I am working on Ubuntu14.04 server and it has 48 CPU cores. I am seeing there is high CPU usage on one core from sar information. So I want to know which processes are running on that core. How should I get all processes running on each CPU core in Ubuntu? I don't have `htop` on server and I cannot install it. But I have `top` and `ps`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
ps -eLF
```

- -e Select all processes.
- -L show threads, possibly with LWP and NLWP columns
- -F  extra full format. See the -f option, which -F implies.

and look at the `PSR` column to get the core that the process/thread is running on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 ps aux | less
```

Where :
A : Select all processes
u : Select all processes on a terminal, including those of other users
x : Select processes without controlling ttys